# such as A and B OR such as A or B

Tags: grammar, such

When is it okay to use "or" instead of "and" with "such as"? 
Been researching this for a while but haven't found a convincing answer.

Considering "such as" is used to give examples, don't we restrict the examples by saying "or"? And if "or" is more apt, why not directly say A, B, or C instead of using "such as"?

The software sends automated emails triggered by certain actions or events such as birthdays and/or anniversaries.

Which would be the correct choice?

The only resources I could find are:
https://forum.oxforddictionaries.com/en/discussion/27/such-as-or-or-and?fbclid=IwAR1-lLoJh73PHhdC1FlNbSPeK0TNo5xgCZz3FvGmQtmJ_WGo76DDapU8m8M

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/such-as?fbclid=IwAR3IawzuEXTjsjfBnwv-hv1w9EUcJWPlODfupOM2sMdZ8KCX86qa-gBJeqo

Comment: Aren't birthdays and anniversaries both examples of events? There is no choice between them as examples of events. Birthdays are AND anniversaries are.

Answer (score 1):

The general difference is **and** is inclusive and **or** is exclusive.

**With nouns:**

When the subject of object is **A and B** or **A or B** and A and B are nouns, e.g. “You can have A and/or B”, **and** indicates “both A as well as B”, whereas **or** indicates either A or B **but not both.**

You can have an apple and an orange. – You can take two fruit.
You can have an apple or an orange. – You can take one fruit.

**With verbs:**

When **and** is used to address verbs, the actions of both verbs may be applied to the object. **And** also states that both actions are possible.

You can **fry** eggs and **boil** them. This is advice for eggs in general - the action of both verbs is possible.

When **or** is used to address verbs (choices of the action applied to **one** object), **or** states that only one of the actions is possible.

“Here is an egg. You can fry it **or** boil it,” i.e. you can do one of the actions but not both - you cannot fry it and then boil it.

EDIT TO ADD

Such as = for example. What follows is a list that contains examples in apposition to a previously mentioned noun or action. Thus we can simplify your example to

It is triggered by {birthdays and anniversaries}. -> either a birthday or an anniversary will trigger it or **both together** will trigger it.

It is triggered by {birthdays} or {anniversaries}. -> Either a birthday or an anniversary will trigger it but both together will not.

In this case, the distinction is **pedantic** and in your case, both are possible and the example is understood as

It is triggered either by birthdays or by anniversaries - it doesn't matter which.

Or

It is triggered by birthdays and it is also triggered by anniversaries.

The problem is with the verb “trigger” – this is a punctual verb. Punctual verbs have no real duration – they are instant. Because they are instant their action cannot affect two things at the same time and therefore the reader imagines the case of a birthday **and** an anniversary occurring at the same time. or imagines only one example - the case of a birthday **or** the case of an anniversary.

The difference is clearer when a durative verb is used. Durative verbs contain an implied duration of action in their meaning. “To read” is a durative verb – it takes time to read.

Compare a durative verb

It is read by the girl and the boy.

It is read by the girl or the boy.

(Grammatically, both are correct but express different ideas.)

With a punctual verb

It finished at 8 pm and 9 pm - this is wrong.

It finished at 8 pm or 9 pm - this is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand your views about "and" and "or", and I'm completely onboard there, but I'm trying to figure these out in the context of "such as". Can you explain the same with a few examples using "such as"? Would be really helpful.

TIA!

Comment: I have edited my answer, see above.

Comment: There is also the interpretation: “*It is triggered by birthdays or anniversaries.*” ->  I can’t remember which one.  The ’or’ meaning only one of the two is correct.  Observationally this results in one always working the other never working and the two together always working.

Answer (score 0):

### *When is it okay to use "or" instead of "and" with "such as"?*

With terms such as *such as*, *like*, and *including*, both *or* and *and* mean the same thing. (Change that first *and* to *or* to see what I mean.)

The phrase *and/or* is always wordy and never necessary. Pick the one that fits.